# Getting the last day of month

Tags: php

I need to write a function which returns which day of the week is the last day of the ongoing month. I can get the last day so far but I don't know how to know which day of the week it is.

Comment: This depends of what date functions that you are using. Check date format option that you can use (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For example myDate->format('t') will return the days in the given month.

Comment: You probably used date() to get that last day. Did you look in the manual about that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$d = new DateTime('last day of this month');
echo $d->format('l'); //Sunday
```

for a specific month\year

```
$d = new DateTime('2019-07-07');
$d->modify('last day of this month');
echo $d->format('l'); //Wednesday
```